# UIImage or CGImage is preferred?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, cgimage

I have a UIView with UIImageView as its subview and i need to change the image in that view while the user swipe it.

I tried it using UIImage, but the app crashes and the memory keeps on rising.

When I tried some googling I got to know that CGImage might be a good choice. Can someone direct me to the right track.

Thanks

Comment: Your problems indicate that you do something wrong (likely regarding memory) in image handling. There will be no difference whether you use CGImage or UIImage unless you fix those problems

Comment: no.. there were no leaks. the problem was the image size were too large. wen i tried with smaller images the worked. thanks you guys

Answer (score 2):

`UIImageView` works with `UIImage`s. `CGImage` is a representation of more low-level image data.

You want to keep using UIImage and concentrate on fixing your bugs. Apparently you are not properly handling memory - retaining and releasing images.  Use debugger to fix the crash, Instruments to figure out why memory consumption goes up. I answered another question with information how it can be solved: [UITextView delegates problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779306/uitextview-delegates-problem/3781050#3781050)

Answer (score 1):

Try loading UIImage to UIImageView by tiling

Comment: this has to be a comment